# JavaFx WebView and JxBrowser alternatives

Tags: java, javafx, jxbrowser, javafx-webengine

Are there any alternatives for the two? I would prefer not to pay for a JxBrowser license and the WebView widget is too slow. Whenever I encounter a page with recaptcha on it the WebView is extremely slow loading images and it never passes the recaptcha test.

Comment: [JCEF](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/java-cef)

Comment: https://github.com/CodeBrig/Journey  
some type of embryo, in the general direction of an OpenSource alternative to JxBrowser.

Answer (score 1):

You can try java-cef (Java Chromium Embedded Framework) : https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/src/master/

To my knowledge, it only works in Swing, so you will have to use a SwingNode.

You can also find some implementations of this framework on Github like pandomium : https://github.com/dzikoysk/pandomium

I don't think that you will find other solution than java-cef, I did a project few month ago in JavaFX with a webView. I tried a lot of things but java-cef and JxBrowser (JxBrowser works great) were the only real options. Or you can go to another technology/language (Electron for example), depending of your necessity.

Comment: Here's JxBrowser vs JCEF comparison: https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/2022/01/10/jxbrowser-and-jcef.html